# How to write Unit Tests on IntegrationFlow components?

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-test, spring-integration-dsl

I have several `@Configuration` classes which include highly complex `IntegrationFlow`s annotated by `@Bean`. I want to make unit tests on every single component that is used in these flows. For example:

```
@Configuration
public class FirstClass{

@Bean
public MessageChannel requestChannel() {
return MessageChannels.direct().get();
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel responseChannel() {
return MessageChannels.direct().get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow myFlow(MessageChannel requestChannel, MessageChannel responseChannel) {
return from(requestChannel)...transform(this::myFirstCustomTransformer)....transform(this::mySecondCustomTransformer)...get();
} 

//sorry for the continues dots, they indicate the existence of other components as well

private Map<String, Object> myFirstCustomTransformer(Map<String, Object> payload){
//do some stuff
}

private String mySecondCustomTransformer(Map<String, Object> payload) {
//do some stuff
}}
```

So I want to test `mySecondCustomTransformer` and `myFirstCustomTransformer` in a unit test. How can I achieve that? Which is the best solution?

***UPDATE**

These transformers include calls to methods which are also members of the same class. So unit tests have to be developed for the remaining methods as well.

Answer (score 2):

The `.transform(this::myFirstCustomTransformer)` created a consumer endpoint component which is able to receive messages via its `inputChannel`. Then it calls your custom code in the `myFirstCustomTransformer` method and the result of the call is sent to the `outputChannel` of the `MessageTransformingHandler`.

So, what you need in your flow is something like `.channel()` before and after that `.transform()`. Then in the unit test you send a test message to the `inputChannel` and verify result in the `outputChannel`.

I agree that we need to come up with something simpler as an out-of-the-box solution there, but let's start from your use-case first of all!

Comment: Thank you Artem for your response. I have thought of this solution and it works. Could you please check for the update in my question? I need to make more unit tests isolating these methods which are called inside the transformers. Any piece of advice? Thank you :)

Comment: The methods called from those `myFirstCustomTransformer` and `mySecondCustomTransformer` are already out of Spring Integration scope. If you need unit test for them, you should call them manually from your tests. If they are `private`, you don't have choice unless make them visible somehow: or `@VisibleForTesting` or reflection.